# Return inside map function is not working

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to get product details like price, discount by the id i'm getting from my cart. This return function is returning null. but working perfectly in console.log.

```
async function store (req,res) { 
    const item = req.session.cart;
    const cart = new Cart(item);
    const results = cart.generateArray();
    let result = [];
    result = results.map(item => { 
        Products.findOne({'_id': item.id}, function (err, r) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                return ({
                    product_id: r._id,
                    price: r.price,
                    qty: item.qty,
                    total: r.price*item.qty                
                });
                // this return is not working
            } 
        });      
    });

    let data = await result;
    return res.send(data);
}
```

Comment: Add return in `return Products.findOne`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Promise.all` to solve an array of promises:

```
result = results.map(async item => { 
    try {
        const r = await Products.findOne({'_id': item.id})
        return ({
            product_id: r._id,
            price: r.price,
            qty: item.qty,
            total: r.price*item.qty                
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }  
});

let data = await Promise.all(result);
```

Comment: This is returning Products from database. The return function inside still not working.

Comment: For errors you are returning `undefined`, are failing every of them? Also, if you add `console.log(r)` in the else does it work?

Comment: `console.log(r)` inside else is working but return is not getting the value of `r`

Comment: Since you are using `async/await` I changed the code to use it and avoid node callbacks.

Comment: Good to hear! Not sure but I think you have to use `.exec()` when using node callbacks. For `async/await`, its not necessary.